# Create different rooms for Google Play game Multiplayer

Tags: android, google-play-games, real-time-multiplayer

I want to create three different rooms as follows:
Room 1: All players want to play 10 coins match
Room 2: All players want to play 50 coins match
Room 3: All players want to play 100 coins match

Now, if a player presses the match with 10 coins, only those players can join the room with different players (it's a 2 player match) not the all players pressed 50 coins or 100 coin match.

Please let me know how I do this as the code:

```
Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 1, role);
```

Only sends the role to other players but all players can join the room, either presses the 10, 50 or 100 coin match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my own question, If someone also stuck here:

```
Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 1, role);
```

Here **'role'** represents the player role in the game, like for RPG game role maybe, Shooter, Snipper etc.

Where, for the game variant as I want for the different game mode, set the variant type value as **'int'** to the RoomConfig **'setVariant(variant)'** as below:

```
RoomConfig roomConfig =
                RoomConfig.builder(mRoomUpdateCallback)
                        .setOnMessageReceivedListener(mMessageReceivedHandler)
                        .setRoomStatusUpdateCallback(mRoomStatusCallbackHandler)
                        .setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria)
                        .setVariant(variant)
                        .build();
```

This resolved my problem and works well for different game mode.

Now, In my game, the players playing for 10 coins match auto join for the 10 match players only.